# Remove extra whitespace between string parts in POSIX shell

Tags: shell, sh

Example:

1. Input string: `'a    string   with    "some   extra space"'`
2. Desired output: `'a string with "some   extra space"'`

How do I get from 1. to 2. without using bash-specifics? `sed`, `awk` and all standard utilities are available – even `python3` if need be. Problems:

- string delimiters might be flipped and/or nested – anything between a set of arbitrary quotes should be considered a string and left untouched
- piping through `tr -s ' '` removes the spaces in the last string
- `xargs` removes string delimiters (such as `"` in the example)
- `echo $VAR` ignores string boundaries entirely

Comment: Do you have any extra sample input to demonstrate the special cases? Because just re-adding the quotes after xargs removes them (via a conditional checking for whitespace in each word) is the simple/obvious thing.

Comment: Oh -- and `sh`, not `bash`? (That makes a big difference; it's much easier with bash or another shell with proper arrays).

Comment: ...also, do you need the _exact_ quoting type to be preserved? Is it okay if it gets transformed to, say, `a string with some\ \ \ extra\ space` or another semantically-identical result?

Answer (score 0):

Going the Python route:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re, shlex, sys

words = shlex.split(sys.argv[1])
print(' '.join([ f'"{word}"' if re.search(r'\s', word) else word for word in words ]))
```

...wrapped for use from a shell:

```sh
remove_unquoted_spaces() {
  python3 -c '
import re, shlex, sys
words = shlex.split(sys.argv[1])
print(" ".join([ f"\"{word}\"" if re.search(r"\s", word) else word for word in words ]))
' "$@"
}
 
remove_unquoted_spaces 'a    string   with    "some   extra space"'
```

Comment: Okay, this python version does work, thanks! But I've managed to refactor the script such that the original problem became much easier. If you're curious: The string(s) don't get cached in a variable now and are immediately written to `stdout` so that no extra whitespace is inserted in the first place.